# How to get the amount of ETH smart contract with Python and Web3.py?

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I have started using Web3.py for ETH transaction analysis.
I have crawled more than 10000 blocks and most of my transactions look like this:

```
{'blockHash': HexBytes('0x439f47a300d021223aeee060c0daabc03bedb250600890faeea7b27c0d30e0e4'), 'blockNumber': 13395924, 'from': '0x18EEfb2E363B54d9F76d347c4aAACF79553c7dBf', 'gas': 106052, 'gasPrice': 89000000000, 'hash': HexBytes('0x173f992db0b9c96f57799afdec51c7a418b7fa36c5ba8b16acb5d45619f03f3f'), 'input': '0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000a1d8d972560c2f8144af871db508f0b0b10a3fbf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010f0cf064dd59200000', 'nonce': 14, 'r': HexBytes('0x9aba92daac3b8b2858552d0e88a3a3cbf904759942830d1d615a8d98af972fd1'), 's': HexBytes('0x7f5228eba9607f0d2a6cb1c6dc97bc37056a7274fa5ee9283d5962de41a86955'), 'to': '0xaA7a9CA87d3694B5755f213B5D04094b8d0F0A6F', 'transactionIndex': 145, 'type': '0x0', 'v': 38, 'value': 0}
```

As far as I know, if `'value'` is 0 and `'input'` looks like this `'0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000a1d8d972560c2f8144af871db508f0b0b10a3fbf00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010f0cf064dd59200000'` that means that its smart contract.

My quest is, how to get the transacted amount (ERC-20)?

Answer (score 1):

Contract interactions are described by [ABI files](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.3/abi-spec.html). In this case you need [an ABI file for IERC20, or ERC-20 interface](https://ethereumdev.io/abi-for-erc20-contract-on-ethereum/).

Then, with this, you can [create Contract proxy instances](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#). A contract proxy class has [decode_function_input](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.Contract.decode_function_input).

Of course, you need to know which contracts are ERC-20 tokens and that's something you cannot easily know without an external registry. Your best bet is to try to guess whether a smart contract is ERC-20 or not based on some heurestic.